# iOS json identification

Tags: ios, json

I'm having a problem with my code. I have a post connection with my wep.api and it works great. I get the messages that I input. i'm trying to string the json response i get from my web.api and compare it by a string to see if the user goes to the next page. The problem is that even if the information i'm putting is wrong, i'm still being send to the next page. This is my code

```
[5:39:03 PM] Marco Tejada: -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theJson = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]
                        length:[webData length]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



NSScanner *scanner1 = [NSScanner scannerWithString:theJson];
NSLog(@"%@", theJson);
if ([scanner1 scanUpToString:@"{\"ResultCode\": 0,\"ResultMessage\": \"Success log in\"}" intoString: NULL])
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sesepuede"sender:self];

}

else {
    NSLog(@"Username not found");{

    }
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Try Again" message:@"Credentials are incorrect" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    }
}

@end
```

Does anyone knows whats the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be pumping your Json into a string you should be hydrating a nsdictionary and getting your value with a key values pair look up.

```
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonDict);
```